# Measuring performance of READ operation for sorted and unsorted table

Tags: sorting, abap

I want to compare `READ` performance for sorted internal table and standard internal table. According to theory, CRUD operations over sorted tables must be always faster than operations over unsorted tables.

The problem is my program doesn't work and it seems like whichever test is executed first shows better results - in my code below I am testing `READ` for the sorted table first. After that I tested the unsorted table, and surprisingly `READ` operation on unsorted table performed better.

Why is that so? What am I missing?

```
DATA: BEGIN OF was,
        id TYPE i,
        tel TYPE i,
      END OF was,

      tabst LIKE STANDARD TABLE OF was
            with header line,

      tabso LIKE SORTED TABLE OF was
            WITH UNIQUE KEY id tel,

      X TYPE I VALUE 100,

      TA1 TYPE timestampl, TA2 TYPE timestampl,
      TB1 TYPE timestampl, TB2 TYPE timestampl,
      TA TYPE timestampl, TB TYPE timestampl,
      N TYPE I VALUE 1000.

DO X TIMES.
  was-id = sy-index - 1.
  was-tel = sy-index * 2.
  APPEND was TO tabst.
  INSERT was INTO TABLE tabso.
ENDDO.

*Testing performance while
*reading sorted internal table
GET TIME STAMP FIELD TB1.

  DO X TIMES.
    READ TABLE tabso INDEX sy-index INTO was.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.

GET TIME STAMP FIELD TB2.
TB = TB2 - TB1.

*Testing performance while
*reading unsorted internal table
GET TIME STAMP FIELD TA1.

  DO X TIMES.
    READ TABLE tabst INDEX sy-index INTO was.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.

GET TIME STAMP FIELD TA2.
TA = TA2 - TA1.

WRITE: 'TA (unsorted) = ', TA.
WRITE: / .
WRITE: 'TB (sorted) = ', TB.
WRITE: / .
WRITE: 'SORTED tabso'.
WRITE: / .
LOOP AT tabso INTO was.
  WRITE: / was-id, was-tel.
ENDLOOP.
WRITE: / .
WRITE: 'UNSORTED tabst'.
WRITE: / .
LOOP AT tabst INTO was.
  WRITE: / was-id, was-tel.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Sorry, but you read with an index. Of course it will be faster for unsorted table or there will be no difference at all. You will first see the difference if you search by key. Having an index brings you directly to the right place.

Comment: @Jagger I tried using READ TABLE tabst WITH TABLE KEY was-id which shows invalid table error

Comment: Change your index reads to `READ TABLE tabso WITH KEY id = was-id tel = was-tel INTO was.` and `READ TABLE tabst WITH KEY id = was-id tel = was-tel INTO was.`

Comment: I've got a big doubt about the "CRUD" of your assumption: "According to theory, CRUD operations over sorted tables must be always faster". I don't know what is this "theory", but it should only concern the reads. Creation, update and delete are slower for sorted tables because the index needs to be updated, while there is no index for unsorted tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To measure performance, SAP has proposed many built-in tests.

Run the program `RSHOWTIM` (also available via a menu of SE38/SE80 transactions).

The one which you are trying to measure is this one: Linear search (24 ms) versus binary search (1 ms).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are trying read two tables with index number (sy-index). So READ command only get record by index. You need to try with WHERE condition. Also 100 records are not enough for testing.

```
READ TABLE tabso WITH TABLE KEY id = sy-index tel = sy-index INTO was.
READ TABLE tabst WITH KEY id = sy-index tel = sy-index INTO was.
```

Comment: I tried using `READ TABLE tabst WITH TABLE KEY was-id` which shows `invalid table` error

Comment: You need to use different qualifiers for sorted and standart tables. I added examples to my response.